# Apache server 32 binaries vs 64 binaries? what's the difference

Tags: apache-2.2

not sure if this is a silly question...apples and oranges maybe..but...

For Windows I used to download either 32 bit binaries from ASF site or 64 bit binaries from Apache lounge site (for no particular reason). So - that was the way I new what version I have.

I've switched to ubuntu (for educational purposes) and got used to compiling from source...well...you know...make..make install etc.

mmmm

1) So - when I compile apache server from source - what binaries do i get? 32? 64?

2) Are there any benefits from having 64 bit Apache binaries? any cons?

Thnaks guys:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Answer your question:

1) You will get the binaries that the system is running as (ie if you have installed a 64bit system you will get a 64 bit binary)

The quick way to find out is to look at the `uname -a` command, if you see x86_64 it's 64bit, if you see i386/i686 it is 32 bit.

2) You need to run the binary version of your OS generally as there is shared libraries and other items that need to match the architecture of the binary